# Не работает startActivityForResult в пустой активности

Tags: android, activity

Пытаюсь создать новую активность, а в ней `startActivityForResult` вот таким способом:

```
               Activity activity = new Activity() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                        Log.i("RLOG", "result: " + resultCode);
                    }
                };

                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 8700);
```

Но выбивает вот такую вот ошибку:

```
01-28 21:44:25.158 23961-23961/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.rostislav.dugin.osloader, PID: 23961
                                                   rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                                                       at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:386)
                                                       at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:383)
                                                       at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(ActionSubscriber.java:44)
                                                       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
                                                       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                       at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8770)
                                                       at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8726)
                                                       at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8549)
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.presenter.SettingsPresenter.onInstallBochsClick(SettingsPresenter.java:95)
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.view.fragments.SettingsFragment.lambda$setUpViews$3(SettingsFragment.java:119)
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.view.fragments.SettingsFragment$$Lambda$3.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20260)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3810)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3761)
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.util.RawApkInstaller.lambda$installApk$0(RawApkInstaller.java:40)
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.util.RawApkInstaller$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
                                                       at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8759)
                                                       at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8726) 
                                                       at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8549) 
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.presenter.SettingsPresenter.onInstallBochsClick(SettingsPresenter.java:95) 
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.view.fragments.SettingsFragment.lambda$setUpViews$3(SettingsFragment.java:119) 
                                                       at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.view.fragments.SettingsFragment$$Lambda$3.onClick(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848) 
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20260) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

---

Как это исправить и запустить метод в такой активности?

---

Это мне нужно для написания класса, который используется в `Presenter` и передавать активность через 4 слоя класснов, изменяя код `Observable` — вообще не вариант (а не потому что я не знаю, что плохо так делать).

Comment: Явно создавать экземпляр активити – весьма плохая и неправильная затея.

Comment: Никак, ищите другой способ решения вашей задачи.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в результате общения в комментариях мы пришли к выводу, что нельзя таким способом запустить `Activity`, в любом случае нужен запущенный экземпляр.

Единственный способ запустить `startActivityForResult` — это получить ссылку на запущенную `Activity` и выполнить метод через нее.

Answer (score 0):

О жесть!

Активность нельзя создать так, как вы это делаете. Андроид капризен, и вы только можете попросить его о чем-то, но не приказать. К примеру, если вы все таки захотите именно попросить систему запустить новую активность (класс которой у вас реально есть в проекте), то вам как минимум нужно попросить класс имплементирующий Context запустить эту активность для вас (внутри, например своей MainActivity)

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
      ...
      startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SomeOfYourActivity.class), 8700)
    }
}
```

И вообще, почитайте что то об андроиде. Срочно !

Comment: Ну, Вы сразу меня за дурака не принимайте :). Я знаю, что так делать плохо, но надеялся на лучшее. Я творю... такое из-за того, что мне нужно использовать `startActivityForResult` в классе, предназначенном для определенной цели, где сопровождать вызов через Activity, потом Fragment, потом Presenter, потом класс и всовывать вызовы в `Observable` — совсем не вариант.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вас, то в этом классе вам понадобится Context, у кторого вы и вызовете startActivityForResult. Еще один момент, вам необходимо указать в иненте, что за активность должна быть запущена. За дурака не принимаю, поскольку в стектрейсе увидел rx.Observables, что говорит о том, что именно в андроиде новичек, а не в программировании вцелом . Вы создаете анонимный класс активности, но так не будет работать. Еще и в манифесте прописать надо ее...

Comment: И снова мимо! :) В `Intent'e` у меня указано (разве что не активность, а запуск установки приложения). И я хотел запустить `Context`, но, во-первых, у него нет метода `startActivityForResult`, а, во-вторых, мне придётся его создавать аналогичным образом.

Comment: Кстати, про `Observable` я-то и узнал в Android'e. Да и вообще половину своего опыта получил в Android'e. Совсем уж новичком назвать меня нельзя, надеюсь, до слабого джуна уже дотягиваю, но что-то более-менее серьёзное я пытаюсь писать сравнительно недавно. Да и мне всего 15 лет.

Comment: Прошу прощения, нужен не Контекст а FragmentActivity.

Comment: Смысл тот же... Слишком сложно передавать ссылку на эту активность. Тогда пойду другим путем: у меня есть статический класс, который говорит, когда новое приложение установлено (увлекся с RxJava, сделал класс, который получает в ресивер уведомления о установке и рассказывает о нем подписчикам. При чем получилось довольно удобно), буду ждать когда приложение установиться, а не ждать, что сделал пользователь. Если приложение установлено, тогда запущу его, а, если нет, снова открою окно установки (все равно пользователь без этого ничего не сможет сделать :)).